# jquery toggle disrupts background image

Tags: jquery, layout, background, toggle

i use this for my content to fade in when the link is clicked.

```
<script> 
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".box").hide();

    $(".link").click(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $($(this).attr("href")).toggle(300);
    });
}); 
</script>
```

I have a repeat-x background image (clouds) at 'bottom'.
However, whenever the content fades in the bottom background gets disrupted - some background color gets overlayed on the cloud images. After a few seconds the bottom image gets normal, but sometimes you have to use the browser's scroller to make it dissapear.

How do I solve this?

Comment: That sounds like a reflow/repaint bug with the browser you're using.

Comment: it happens with all of them :/